# Find first set consecutive numbers php regex

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I am fairly new to both php and regular expressions and am  having trouble finding my solution. I am not sure if it because I do not know the terms to google or what, but here is my question:

I am trying to use PHP preg_match to find the first set of consecutive numbers in a string. What I mean by consecutive numbers is ANY string where it is uninterrupted numbers.

ex.

'abc123abc' matches: 123
'ghdfk 1 23abc' matches: 1
'2475xyz' matches: 2475
'abc 456 789' matches: 456

I have been looking through regular-expressions.info and google for terms similar to my question topic, but they all seem to return searches for people looking for repeating numbers of specific lengths.

I am trying to parse an address string to the best of my ability, even though it might be horribly entered.

Things I have tried so far that aren't working are in my code:

```
<?php
#$addr = '12-3 3rd street'; #1st Test
$addr = 'RR 3 Box 8411'; #2nd Test
#$addr = '480jacksonrd'; #3rd Test
#$addr = 'N2626prociousmayselrd'; #4th Test

#list($our['StreetNum'], $our['StreetName']) = explode(" ", $our['Address'], 2);

#preg_match('/.+(?=[^0-9])/s',$addr,$Matches);
#preg_match('/[0-9]*/',$addr,$Matches);
preg_match('/(?<=\[^0-9]).+?(?=[^0-9])/s',$addr,$Matches);

$our['StreetNum'] = $Matches[0];

$our['StreetNum'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $our['StreetNum']);

echo ('First Match?: ' . $Matches[0] . '<br>'); #For Testing
echo ('Second Match?: ' . $Matches[1] . '<br>'); #For Testing
echo ('StrLen of StreetNum: ' . strlen($our['StreetNum']) . '<br>');
echo ('StrPos of StreetNum: ' . strpos($addr,$our['StreetNum']) . '<br>');

$our['StreetName'] = substr($addr, strlen($our['StreetNum'])+strpos($addr,$our['StreetNum']));

echo ('Street Original: ' . $addr . '<br>');
echo ('Street Number: ' . $our['StreetNum'] . '<br>');
echo ('Street Name: ' . $our['StreetName'] . '<br>');
?>
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking.  Try this:

```
if preg_match('/\d+/', $my_string, $matches)
    return $matches[0];
```

You just need to search for digits, and return the match.

Answer (score 3):

`/[0-9]+/` as `preg_match` should be enough.
You search for any 1 or more numbers.

```
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $addr, $Matches)
```

Or

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $addr, $Matches)
```

Comment: hmm, I wonder why my preg_match('/[0-9]*/',$addr,$Matches); didn't work when I tested it. '*' should be similar to '+', only instead of 1 or more, it is 0 or more?

Comment: Because your string always matches 0 numbers. You should have at least 1 number or more. If you did a `preg_match_all` you would see a lot of empty values and also the right value.